# How to redirect to a asp.net core razor page (no routes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here I have a razor cs page:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(){
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return Page(); 
  }

  return RedirectToPage('Pages/index.cshtml'); 

}
```

And a cshtml page:

```
@page
@using RazorPages

@model IndexModel
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" id="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to redirect to the same page on form submit but I keep getting 400 error. Is it possible to do the redirect without using routes and just go to cshtml file in the url?

Comment: return View(viewname);

Comment: this is a razor page

Comment: of type PageModel

Comment: Remove "Pages" from your redirect path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in view;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="submit" id="Submit">
}
```

Comment: This works when RedirectToPage('Pages/index.cshtml');  is changed to RedirectToPage('Index');

Comment: You could also just use RedirectToPage();

Answer (score 12):

@Roman Pokrovskij
This might be way too much old but if you want to redirect to an Area you should:

```
return RedirectToPage ( "/Page", new { Area = "AreaName" } );
```

Answer (score 10):

check out the MS page 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio

The associations of URL paths to pages are determined by the page's location in the file system. The following table shows a Razor Page path and the matching URL:

```
File name                       path matching URL
---------------------------     ----------------------
/Pages/Index.cshtml             / or /Index
/Pages/Contact.cshtml           /Contact
/Pages/Store/Contact.cshtml     /Store/Contact
/Pages/Store/Index.cshtml       /Store or /Store/Index
```

URL generation for pages supports relative names. The following table shows which Index page is selected with different RedirectToPage parameters from 
Pages/Customers/Create.cshtml:

```
RedirectToPage(x)           Page
------------------------    ---------------------
RedirectToPage("/Index")    Pages/Index
RedirectToPage("./Index");  Pages/Customers/Index
RedirectToPage("../Index")  Pages/Index
RedirectToPage("Index")     Pages/Customers/Index
```

Comment: Hi, could I ask you how we should redirect to pages in the areas: /Areas/MyArea/Pages/Index.cshtml?

Comment: The big GOTCHA for me was thinking I needed "Pages" or "/Pages" in the path. Once I removed it everything worked. REMOVE "Pages" FROM YOUR REDIRECT PATH.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect to a different page after some action:

```
return Redirect("~/Page/YourAction");
```

Comment: Thank so i have RedirectToPage but it didn;t worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
return RedirectToPage("./Index");
```